# Powershell | how to Excluding Sub OU

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need a script to disable all user in a specific OU but not the users in the sub OU
this is my actual ps script and i dont know how to exclude the sub OU in the MainOU,
this script will run every friday night. the AD is onprem.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "ou=MainOU, ou=User, ou=Test, dc=local, dc=us" | Disable-ADAccount
```

i hope someone can help me so i can learn how to exlude ou's in other ps scripts

Comment: use `-SearchScope OneLevel`

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help, i found a solution, try and error :)

```
#Connect to Main OU
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "ou= MainOU, ou=User, ou=Test, dc=local, dc=ch" |

#Exclude Sub OU
Where-Object {$_.DistinguishedName -notmatch 'OU1 | OU2'} |

#Disable all accounts in Main OU
Disable-ADAccount
```

I hope i can help other users with this code